# make clang complete autofill header files - Is it possible?

Tags: c++, vim, clang-complete

Is  there a way for clang_complete to display a popup when I am writing my includes say for example

```
#include <(popup should open)
#include <boost/(popup should open)>
```

I created a file called  `.clang_complete` that has the location to the header files however that does not seem to work. Any suggestions on how I could accomplish that ? or if there is another extension that could help me do that ?

This is in my .vimrc

```
let g:cliang_user_options='|| exit 0'
let g:clang_close_preview=1
:set completeopt-=preview
```

Comment: You should use [the plugin's issue tracker](https://github.com/Rip-Rip/clang_complete/issues) instead of a generic QA site. Troopers suck, be a sniper!

Comment: Did you figure this one out? I would like header completion too!

Comment: @Jose There is now [corresponding issue in the tracker](https://github.com/Rip-Rip/clang_complete/issues/466).